# In Sitecore, how to view the content of the submit queue file?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-analytics

So in the Sitecore site, in Data/Submit Queue, there is a file without an extension that is representing the content of the Submit Queue.

If you try viewing it as a text file, it shows some content, but there is some strange characters in the mix.

So, has someone made an application to view this file? Is it suppose to be in a specific format that should opened with an application able to view that format?

Extra info: Sitecore 8.0, no there is nothing about it in the control panel or in sitecore/admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This file contains the analytics data that was not flushed to the Mongo database.

In case xDB collection server is unavailable, Sitecore would/must handle this situation correctly. There is a special 'Submit Queue' mechanism introduced that flushes captured data to local server hard drive ( 'Data\Submit Queue' folder by default ) in case xDB is not available.

When xDB is up again, a background worker would submit the data saved on disk, so no data is lost.

As a quick suggestion on this I recommend you to check whether your MongoDB server is available for your Sitecore instance. Once it becomes available, all data from the file should be flushed to the xDB.

The submit queue file stores serialized values as follows: first value - number of entities, second value - position of the next entity, which must be submitted to xDB, the next values contain serialized analytics data.

The submit queue is processed using this class: **Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.SubmitQueue.FileSubmitQueue**

If you want to debug to see how is processed decompile the class and create your own class and replace in **Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.confing**

```
 <submitQueue>
    <queue type="Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.SubmitQueue.FileSubmitQueue, Sitecore.Analytics" singleInstance="true" />
 </submitQueue>
```

Answer (score 6):

Mark is right, the submit queue isn't meant for users to view.  A couple of months ago, I wrote a post on this exact subject.

https://citizensitecore.com/2016/07/01/xdb-session-info-and-mongodb-availability/

From Akinori Taira, a member of the xDB product team:

> In the event that the collections database is unavailable, there is a
>   special ‘Submit Queue’ mechanism that flushes captured data to the
>   local hard drive (the ‘Data\Submit Queue’ folder by default).  When
>   the collections database comes back online, a background worker
>   process submits the data from the ‘Submit Queue’ on disk.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Look at that. Updated your answer into a high quality answer, and you have 5 upvotes =)

Answer (score 3):

No, you're not meant to be opening the Submit Queue and do anything with it.

It is used by xDB (in your case) to submit data, when the xDB cannot be reached. It will be a format related to MongoDB in some way, but I've never seen any formal documentation for it.

References:

- http://sitecoreart.martinrayenglish.com/2015/04/sitecore-xdb-cloud-edition-what-you.html
- [Sitecore 8.1: Purpose of Submit Queue and MediaIndexing folders under $(dataFolder)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35098744/sitecore-8-1-purpose-of-submit-queue-and-mediaindexing-folders-under-datafold)

Comment: Actually, the format is based on .NET binary serialization of session data. Source: am the author.